# Postgres SQL to split values from a string into multiple columns based on the format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data in Telephone column, something as below:

```
with t (id,telephone) as (values
(1234560,'(345) 908-1234 '),
(1234561,'(345) 908-1234;ext=1234'),
(1234562 ,'(345) 908-1234;ext=12345'),
(1234563 ,'(345) 908-12345;ext=12345'),
(1234564 ,'1234567;ext=12345'),
(1234565 ,'123ABC;ext=12345'),
(1234566 ,'Ext=12345'),
(1234567 ,'+1123456789')
)
select * from t
```

Only  telephone numbers with (XXX) XXX-XXXX or (XXX) XXX-XXXX;ext=XXX(ext can be unlimited) formats should be considered as Valid and remaining all are considered as invalid

Used `REGEXP_MATCHES` for identifying the valid format of telephone.

**Case #1**
If its valid then we need to split values as below :
first 3 chars - Area
next  3 chars - Exchange
last 4  chars - Line
Anything chars after ;Ext= should be into Ext number

This above case#1 working as expected

**Case #2**

Scenario 1 : If invalid format contains any chars between A-Z or only EXT=XXXX it should be ignored(NULL) out entirely

Scenario 2 : If its any other invalid format any chars before EXT should be inserted into Alternate number and any chars after EXT should be inserted into  EXT column

I am stuck with above scenario 1  related to Case2(for ids 65,66)

Please find below DB Fiddle for the code and expected output : [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/K7AIlE58)

Comment: I believe I saw this same question about 12 hours ago.  What happened to the earlier question?

Comment: That particular is question is for identifying if its valid format from the string. This is kind of extension for splitting the values for invalid format

Comment: I'm unclear when Alternate/Extension  should or shouldn't be populate. Please be precise, as if you're programming a computer. For example, you say to remove special characters; what about `+` (International dialing code) what about `#` or `\t`? Is it ONLY alphabetical characters that don't get removed? If you can write a "program" (be it it in pseudo code), we can translate that in to sql/regex. Any gaps or ambiguities that you leave with just prompt more questions.

Comment: My bad. Updated the question and DB fiddle.  An alternate field should only populate if not  '^\((\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4})'. No need to strip any special chars. Anything before ;EXT=XXXX should be inserted into column

Comment: Why don't rows 65 and 66 have a value in Alternate?  Why doesn't row 66 have a value in Extension?

Comment: 65 : As string contains chars between `A-Z` we should not pass that into any column ; 66 - Similarly when string contains only `EXT=XXXX` we should not pass into any column. Both cases are invalid formats and should be NULLED out

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/BpzNzuMS ?

Comment: Thanks , this works. I added an extra condition to remove NULL rows